# call function after multiple loops of fetch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If i want to call doStuff()
when multiple loops of fetch are finnish, how would i approach it ?

im assuming i need to call a function every time a fetch is done and check if concat of both array length is at the last one ?

```js
let array1 = [1,2]
let array2 = [7,8]

array1.map(function(item){
  fetch("/api/execution/"+item, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  })
});

array2.map(function(item){
  fetch("/api/something/"+item, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  })
});

//call doStuff only when all the fetchs are done

function doStuff(){
  console.log("yay")
}
```

Comment: Store the result of your maps, and then use `Promise.all(maps).then(function () {....`

Comment: The use of map here is very strange.  The values are not persisted.  This should probably be using `each()` instead, pending any other logical issues.

Comment: @Keith first need to `return` each `fetch()` in order for the return value of `map()` to be meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `.map()` to launch the requests but you're not saving the returned Promise instances.

```
let p1 = array1.map(function(item){
  return fetch("/api/execution/"+item, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
});
```

And similarly for `array2`.  You can then concatenate the two arrays of Promises and use `Promise.all()`:

```
let p1 = array1.map(function(item){
  return fetch("/api/execution/"+item, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
});

let p2 = array2.map(function(item){
  return fetch("/api/something/"+item, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  })
});

Promise.all(p1.concat(p2)).then(function(fetchedValues) {
  // all fetch calls are finished
});
```

Comment: Can you give a complete example ?

Comment: @MartinLarocque done, I just needed to double-check a couple of things

Comment: Will that also work if in p2 i have another promise inside,

for example array2.map(promise.then(anotherPromise))

Comment: So long as the `p` arrays consist of promises, yes. Note that `.then()` returns a Promise.